# How to implement different activation functions in a layer of a neural network in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following line creates a layer of size three with the sigmoid activation function on each neuron:

```
out = layers.dense(inputs=inp, units=3, activation=sigmoid)
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
out = layers.dense(inputs=inp, units=3, activation=[sigmoid sigmoid relu])
```

In essence, the first two neurons contain the sigmoid activation function and the third neuron contains the relu activation function.

My question is: How do I implement this?

I would appreciate it if someone could answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and cleanest way is to just create 2 outputs layers:

```
sigmoid_out = layers.dense(inputs=inp, units=2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
relu_out = layers.dense(inputs=inp, units=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

You can then concat both layers if you want :

```
out = tf.concat([sigmoid_out, relu_out], axis=1)
```